# Cannot display username after they're logged in

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know why username cannot be displayed after they're logged in. Tell me if any code is not right. Here are my several code.

Index.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
if(!empty($_POST['noic']) && !empty($_POST['katalaluan']))
{?>

 <?php 
$noic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['noic']);
$katalaluan = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['katalaluan']));

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE noic = '".$noic."'  
AND katalaluan = '".md5."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $_SESSION['noic'] = $noic;
$_SESSION['katalaluan'] = $katalaluan;
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['nama'] = $nama;  //edited
    echo("<script>location.href = 'userplatform.php?     
id=$row[noic]';</script>");
}
else
{
    echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a  
href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
}
}
else
{
?>
```

After above code is the html code which is login form.

And this is several code after user logged in.

userplatform.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("connection.php");
$getId=$_REQUEST["id"];

echo $_SESSION['nama'];
    ?>
```

What's wrong them?please help me...

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` in your `index.php` file? Also, __PLEASE__ don't use `mysql_` methods. They are deprecated and dangerous. Use `PDO`, or at the very least `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: I call the session_start() in connection.php

Comment: Well, in that case you don't need it again in `userplatform.php`. Once is all it takes.

Comment: In you `userplatform.php` dont put `session_start` because already in `connection.php`. And just after `include` line echo the session value.

Comment: Best would be remove session start from `connection.php` and put on each file (on very top) `index.php` /`userplatform.php`

Comment: so, how do we know if your POST arrays aren't failing/HTML form.

Comment: I strongly suggest you not use this code at all; it's unsafe on too many levels. You're not live or going live with this, are you?

Comment: I've followed what u said. But error occured. It cannot call the value from database

Comment: *"But error occured"* being what exactly? Error reporting and error checking on the query are what? Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and where is the HTML form for this?

Comment: `'".md5."'` that is also failing here; it's an undefined constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you assigning the value of `$nama`? Have you tried something like this `$_SESSION['nama'] = "test_name";` and see if `test_name` would be returned in userplatform.php?

Comment: i've called it in connection.php. It is in line 2 from Index.php and userplatform.php

Comment: *"I call the session_start() in connection.php – ila dila 3 mins ago"* - So, that's not it. You should wait and pay attention to comments before posting an answer.

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$_POST['nama']` in the index.php to make sure the value is populated? You might want to comment out the redirect for the test.

Comment: There was no comment at the time and I could not post a comment as must have 50 rep.

Comment: @T.Daves I completely understand and with time/experience, you'll quickly learn that questions like this usually have hidden / unknown aspects of code that they usually leave out, which is why I don't post answers on things I don't know or have a feeling they are already using.

Comment: I don't know what to do right now. I'm confused. I've already edited them in Index.php . But it's same. the username cannot displayed at the top of page

Comment: Where are you assigning the value of `$nama`? Have you tried something like this `$_SESSION['nama'] = "test_name";` and see if `test_name` would be returned in userplatform.php?

Comment: Omg i did it. first i've changed the code like u said @T.Daves. and yes the test_name displayed on the top of the page. n then I tried to change them like this $_SESSION['nama'] = $row["nama"]; n it's worked. thank u so much for the solution sir. I'm very happy right now. btw sorry for this late reply.